# Error when reading/writing in the temp directory (using arulesSequences in R-studio)

Tags: r, rstudio, temp

When I run the following code:

```
s1 <- cspade(x, parameter = list(support = 0.1, maxsize = 1, maxlen = 1),
    control = list(verbose = TRUE))
```

I receive the following error:

```
Total elapsed time 0.00286102
1 partition(s), 0 MB [0.12s]
mining transactions ...MINSUPPORT 1 out of 4 sequences  
reading sequences ...cannot open file 
'C:\Users\ERKANE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpohPsWy\cspade3894f1b4b9f.out': No 
such file or directoryError in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

When I check the directory, I do not see any `.out` file. I have attempted to change the TMPDIR to another location, but still received the same error. I run r-studio as admin, but still receive the same error. I am able to create a file in the same directory `write.csv(mtcars,paste(tempdir(),"mtcars.csv",sep="\\"))`. Any ideas?

I am using R version 3.5.1 and RStudio-1.1.456.